# Can the MouseUp event be added to the Windows Forms scroll bars..?

Tags: vb.net

I have an HScrollbar on a form in VB.Net 2012. I would like the slider to snap back to zero when the mouse button is released. But HScrollbar and VScrollbar do not have MouseUp events. I am able to simulate the behavior somewhat by using MouseLeave, but it's imprecise and problematic.

I know a class can be extended, but I don't know if it applies in this case. Is it possible to extend the scrollbar classes to add the MouseUp event? If so, how?

Here is an example of my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub HScrollBar1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.MouseLeave
        HScrollBar1.Value = 0
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried the `MouseCaptureChanged` event?

Answer (score 2):

The combination of `MouseCaptureChanged` and `ValueChanged` events worked for me:

```
Private Sub HScrollBar1_MouseCaptureChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.MouseCaptureChanged
    If Not HScrollBar1.Capture Then
        HScrollBar1.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HScrollBar1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.ValueChanged
    If Not HScrollBar1.Capture Then
        HScrollBar1.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```